# Conditional problem with Bernoulli variables

Tags: conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Let $S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}$ and $T_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{k}X_{k}$
with all $X_{k}$ and $ Y_{k}$ are mutually independent and of law Bernoulli respectively of parameters p and q. 
Let $N=inf\{n>0 \mid T_{n+1}=1\}$

The question is to show that for all k , we have

$P(X_{k} \mid N=n)=P(X_{k} \mid Y_{k}X_{k}=0)$ for all k and $P(\cap_{k=1}^{n}(X_{k}=x_{k} \mid N=n)=\prod_{k=1}^{n} P(X_{k}=x_{k} \mid N=n)$ for all $x_{k} \in \{0, 1\}^{n}$.

Comment: Can you please clarify the second statement? What is the intersection over (and hence the product)? It is it over $k = 1,...,n$, and so for all $x = (x_1, ..., x_n) \in \{0,1\}^n$? Also, does $P(X_k \mid N = n)$ mean "law of $X_k$ given $N = n$"?

Comment: yes the product is from 1 to n and the intersection also.

Comment: How about the other part?

Comment: I just edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

The event $[N=n]$ tells you that $X_kY_k=0$ for $k=1, \ldots, n$. Because the variables are independent, $X_jY_j$ is not informative about $X_k$ unless $j=k$, so
\begin{align*}
P[X_k=1\mid N=n] &= P[X_k=1\mid X_1Y_1=0, \cdots, X_nY_n=0] \\
&= P[X_k=1\mid X_kY_k=0]\\
&=P[Y_k=0]\\
&=1-q.
\end{align*}
This reasoning can be extended for each $k$, again by independence, so 
\begin{align*}
P[X_1=x_1, \ldots, X_n=x_n \mid N=n] &= P[X_1=x_1, \ldots, X_n=x_n \mid X_1Y_1=0, \ldots X_nY_n=0]\\
&= P[X_1=x_1\mid X_1Y_1=0] \cdots P[X_n=x_n|X_nY_n=0] \\
&= P[X_1=x_1 \mid N=n] \cdots P[X_n=x_n \mid N=n]\\
&= \prod_{k=1}^n P[X_k=x_k\mid N=n]
\end{align*}